# Delete oldest data with Talend

Tags: talend

I need to delete the oldest address of each user I have in a database with Talend. I assume that all the users in the database have more than one address. The user must be in the “student” user group.
The address is in the user_address table (example row included):

```
   id   user_id    address_1      address_2     city     country     created_date
    1      1      1 Rosebery Pl                 London      UK        2017-03-12
```

The user group is in the user_group table (example row included):

```
   user_id    usergroup
      1        Student
```

What components do I need? This is what I have so far but not sure it is correct.

tFileList ->Iterate -> tFileProperties -> Main -> tUnite -> Main -> tSortRow -> Main -> tSampleRow -> Main -> tFileDelet

Comment: You can partition your table by range "created_date" then simply drop the partition you don't need or what you call old Data

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the data in `ASC` order by using `tDBInput` component to give the oldest data on top:

```sql
select id, user_id, address_1, address_2, city, country
from student
order by created_date ASC
```

[Get the First Match record using tMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9CWY.png)

[The image represents the component mapping to delete the oldest record in address table using tDBOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktmkO.png)